# JQGrid post data during edit

Tags: jquery, wcf, jqgrid

I have a JQgrid whcih is working fine when loading. But i want to send some additional data to a wcf service. I tried editData,Serializeeditdata but unable to do it.Can anyone please help me in sending it. I searched and tried a lot and implemented but its of no use. If i add parameter for my save method jqgrid is throwing error.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
                url: "../Service.svc/GetData",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),`enter code here`
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                colNames: ['Id', 'Value'],
                colModel: [{ name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 1, align: 'left', editable: false},
                        { name: 'Value', index: 'Value', width: 270, align: 'left', editable: true},
                       ],                
                pager: jQuery('#pageNavigation'),              
                editurl: "../Service.svc/SaveData",
                loadError: ShowError
            }).navGrid('#pageNavigation', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false }, //options
                {// edit options
                editData: {firstName: 'Test'},
                height: 100, width: 230, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeOnEscape: true
            }
        });
```

//WCF CODE

```
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> 
        Public Function GetData As String Implements Iservice.GetData
        End Function

        Public Sub SaveData(ByVal firstName As String) Implements Iservice.SaveData
         //Retreive name and Do Some operation
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you also need a `<WebInvoke>` attribute decorating your `SaveData` method?  Do you have that and it's not part of the code that you supplied?  Otherwise, you need to provide that so that your method is accessible as a WCF call.

```
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:="...", ...)>   
Public Sub SaveData(ByVal firstName As String) Implements Iservice.SaveData
 //Retreive name and Do Some operation
End Sub
```

Comment: I have it as  <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)> i dint mention here. It keeps on giving me  error Status: Internal Server Error Error code: 500. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Are you able to step through your code?  Sounds like you have an error somewhere in your SaveData method.

Comment: Its not even going into the functin. I can step through get method and debug it. But Here its give me that error as soon as i click submit button.

Comment: Forget to mention and if i make my SaveData method without any params it calls but i need to pass values to the method.

Comment: Do you have an error message that you get back?  Also, when you POST your data, can you view the submit in Fiddler or Firebug?  Do you see your values being POST'ed to the server?

Comment: Yeah i see them. If you have implemented before can you please point me to a sample of something..